# How to use data from angularfire response

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to work data received from an angularfire object response. The data I am looking for is present "-KKndSv4p0NHgSY-lzcT" But I have no way of targeting it since angularfire is inserting other properties. How can I work with just the data stored in the firebase database?

```
{    
  $$conf:Object
  $id: "list"
  $priority:null
  -KKndSv4p0NHgSY-lzcT: true
   __proto__ : Object
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nature of AngularFire, but these `$` keys are to be ignored. What you're likely looking for is to use a `$firebaseArray()` rather than a `$firebaseObject()`.

The array will give you back an array of one item with a value of `true`.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed.